# How to use JSONB operations with pg-promise

Tags: node.js, postgresql, jsonb, pg-promise, node-postgres

I'm struggling with pg-promise and getting it to work with JSONB. I'm using prepared statements, i've attempted two variations for this SQL command (i just wanna udpate the jsonb column with a new set of values, basically appending):

```
  db.none({
    name: 'updateLike',
    text:`UPDATE posts
    SET likes_by = jsonb_set(likes_by, '{$1~}', '$2~'),
    likes_count = likes_count + 1
    WHERE post_id = $3`,
    values: [user_id, username, pid]
  })
```

or

```
  db.none({
    name: 'updateLike',
    text:`UPDATE posts
          SET likes_by = likes_by || '{"$1": "$2"}',
          likes_count = likes_count + 1
          WHERE post_id = $3`,
    values: [user_id, username, pid]
  })
```

It gives me errors like:

**error: invalid input syntax for type json**

or

**error: could not determine data type of parameter $1**

Anyone done this before?

Comment: You cannot combine things like `$1~` with `Prepared Statements`. The former refers to query-formatting within `pg-promise`, while the latter is specifically for server-side query formatting, which means `$1~` goes into the server directly, which the server does not recognize. Best is not to use `Prepared Statements`, unless you absolutely have to, then you will have access to all the nice query formatting implemented by `pg-promise`. It is a compromise ;)

Comment: Understood. I was using prepared statements to avoid any SQL-injection. But I did read about using SQL names and helpers. So I'm assuming I should use that  instead?

Comment: Yes, and the [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names) in this case will protect you against SQL injection just the same.

Comment: Understood, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
  db.none(`UPDATE posts
           SET likes_by = likes_by || '{$1~: $2~}',
           likes_count = likes_count + 1
           WHERE post_id = $3#`,
           [user_id, username, pid]
  )
```

Works. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that the part with `$3#` isn't what you should use. In such cases it should be either properly escaped, by default, or not be escaped at all, i.e. be a [Raw Text](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#raw-text).

Comment: I must have misunderstood what :value does then. I'll use :raw instead, I just wanted to use a provided integer value in that particular placeholder. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If you are passing in an integer, then you do not need any filter there at all, just regular `$3` should suffice.